# How to run Wamp server?

Tags: apache

I have a wamp server as well as Xampp installed. I am unable to start my wamp server. When I try to start services, it stops in orange state, never moves to green. But I am getting to see my local host in browser with Xamp under this situation. Can any one help me how to get my wamp server only running.
Sorry for being naive. I am just starting.

Comment: Have you tried stopping xamp and then starting wamp?

Comment: Both will use the same service ports, so they become mutually exclusive. To start one, you need to stop the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using `Ubuntu 14.0` you can try somewhat like this in the Terminal Window by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T`

**Stopping web server apache2**

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` (find the path where your xampp server is located)

**Starting XAMPP**

`sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run` (find the path where your wamp server is located)

**For Windows**

1. Press Windows Key + R or go to `run`
2. Type `services.msc`
3. Then stop the service for `Xampp Server`

If Apache **is not** running as a Windows Service:
you use the Xampp Control Panel Application to stop and start Apache.

I also experienced the same problem and I hope it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I stopped my Apache service, (Windows 7), I am able to start my Wamp  server started. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help you @Mohan

Answer (score 0):

**INSTALLING**

- Double click on the downloaded file and just follow the instructions.
  Everything is automatic. The WampServer package is delivered whith
  the latest releases of Apache, MySQL and PHP.

  Once WampServer is installed, you can manually add aditionals Apache,
  Php or MySql (only VC9, VC10 and VC11 compiled) versions.
  Explanations will be provided on the forum.

  Each release of Apache, MySQL and PHP has its own settings and its
  own files (datas for MySQL).

**Using wampserver**

- The “www” directory will be automatically created (usually
  c:\wamp\www)

  Create a subdirectory in “www” and put your PHP files inside.

  Click on the “localhost” link in the WampSever menu or open your
  internet browser and go to the URL : http://localhost

[Installing Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#post-118)